# StandardSetController - Can I override New, Edit, Clone Buttons?

Tags: visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce

For creating list button in relationlist, I changed my constructor `StandardController` to `StandardSetController`. After changing constructor in `VisualForce Page`, the standard `Clone`, `Edit`, and `New` buttons are not overriding. Does `StandardSetController` only work for listbuttons, and not for standard buttons? What can I do to override standard buttons?

Comment: Better providing code could give more weight to this question.

Comment: FYI it comes across as fairly rude to use that ellipsis style question mark (`..?`). Not sure if usage is more common where you are but I would advise to use just the question mark for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StandardSetController is used in order to extend functionality on ListViews. In addition, if you open a List view (Open object tab and click on Go! button) you cannot find Save / Edit / Clone buttons.

StandardController takes care of a single record and yo can use it in order to override Standard buttons.

Find [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) a good example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override standard button the VF page MUST be using the StandardController. You can create a custom button named new and use it and hide the Standard new button (Except on list view)

Answer (score 0):

StandardsetController allow you to create list controllers, doesnt work for single object. You must use StandardContoler to make new,edit button work.